# Method gets called earlier than defined

Tags: java, oop

I've got these lines of code:

```
Family family = new Family("A");
Man man = new Man("B");
Woman woman = new Woman("C");
family.addPerson(man);
family.addPerson(woman) 
System.out.println(family.toString() + ": " + family.getFamilyMembers());
```

This is the family class:

```
public class Family {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Person> family = new ArrayList<>();

    public Family(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        this.family.add(person);
    }

    public String getFamilyMembers() {
        for (Person person : this.family) {
            System.out.println(person.toString());
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

What I don't understand is that when I run the program the family.getFamilyMembers(); gets executed before family.toString() gets. Is there any explanation for this?

Console output:

```
B
C
A:
```

Comment: You never even added `man` and `woman` to `family`. Make sure the problem is reproducible for us.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to include the family.addPerson(man) and family.addPerson(woman) in my question!

Comment: `getFamilyMembers()` will run before `sout` method to evaluate what should it print

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I don't understand is that when I run the program the `family.getFamilyMembers();` gets executed before `family.toString()` gets. Is there any explanation for this?

It isn't getting executed before `toString()`. It is getting executed before `System.out.println()`, that prints the *result* of `toString()`

Since you print inside of `getFamilyMembers()`, and `getFamilyMembers` is evaluated before the print statement, you see the results of `getFamilyMembers()` before `toString`

If you changed your `getFamilyMembers()` method to return the names of the `Person` objects instead of printing them, then you'll see the results you expected:

```
public String getFamilyMembers() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Person person : this.family) {
        sb.append(person.toString();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or if you are fine with the format of

```
[A, B, C]
```

You can just `return family.toString();`

Comment: So in other words, `toString()` gets executed first, then `getFamilyMembers()` **which has print statements of its own**, and lastly the `System.out.println()` in the main method.

Comment: But returning will make the loop stop

Comment: @Ezrab_ No, concat the `String`'s inside the loop, then return after the loop

Answer (score 0):

I went with the answer @GBlodgett gave me:

```
    public String getFamilyMembers() {
    String a = "";
    for (Person person : this.family) {
        a = a.concat(person.toString());
    }
    return a;
}
```

outputs:

```
A: BC
```